# .Net Core 1.1 Generic Repository find by string error

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

So I have been trying to implement a generic repository and need to be able to find entities in the database based on a string.  The only problem I have is that DbSet doesn't contain the `Find()` method as I was expecting.

Does anyone know how I can keep my repository generic while also trying to return entities based on a string value in the database??  Here is my repository class

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    protected readonly DbContext Context;
    protected DbSet<T> DbSet;

    public Repository(NLPDbContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
        DbSet = context.Set<T>();
    }

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        Context.Set<T>().Add(entity);

        Save();
    }

    public T Get<TKey>(TKey id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public T GetByEmail<TKey>(TKey Email)
    {
        //No .Find method????
        return DbSet.Find(Email);
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return DbSet;
    }

    public void Update(T entity)
    {
        Save();
    }

    private void Save()
    {
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can get around this issue?? I need a way of returning a single entry based on a string value, but also keeping the repository generic??

Any help will be great thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make certain that you are referencing `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` of version 1.1.0 or more, as `DbSet` does not have a Find method [before this version](http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/dbset).

> In previous versions of EF, a convenience method called Find is
>   available, which is used to query the context for an entity by primary
>   key value

So, be aware that `Find` should be performed based on entity's primary key.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Looks as though i was using V1.0.5 of EFCore which cant have had the Find method implemented.  Your answer worked perfectly.  I just updated all my NuGet packages to V1.1.0  Ideally i would be using Core 2.0 but im restricted to using older versions.  Thanks again